# How to get distinct value from Lucene Field

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am trying to make a search from Lucene index. I have created an index using StandardAnalyzer 
I have the data to be indexed like following

course 
BCA
MCA
BCA
BCA
MCA

When i search on course ="BCA" it returns me 3 times BCA but i want it should give the distinct values ie only once

I am using the following code

```
     try {
         File indexDir = new File("D:\\indexdirectory\\");
         Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);
         IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);
         QueryParser parser1;
         parser1= new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "course", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
         Query query = parser1.parse("BCA");
         int maxhits = 5000;
         TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, maxhits);
         ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
         int len = hits.length;
         int docId;
         Document d;
             for(int j=0;j<len;j++) {
                 docId = hits[j].doc;
                 d = searcher.doc(docId);                
                 String c = d.get("course"); 
                 System.out.println("Course = "+c);
             } 

     }catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Exception occured"+e);
     }
```

it returns BCA 3 times not only once as expected.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you have a document with a field with the contents: "`BCA MCA BCA BCA MCA`", and when searching, it returns that same document three times?

Comment: Yes exactly, it return three times but i want only single time.

Comment: The behavior you want is standard behavior.  Either you are using some sort of non-standard `IndexSearcher`, or something like that, or more likely you are mistaken about the contents of your index.  I would guess that three identical documents exist in the index you are searching, probably placed there by consecutive runs of an index build process in which the existing index was not overwritten.  Have you tried using [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) to view the contents of your index?